# create querystring using lambda from List T

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

i am having some difficulties creating a proper select.

i have my custom class:

```
internal class classA{
        internal string FieldName { get; set; }
        internal string FieldValue { get; set; }
        internal bool IncludeInChecksum { get; set; }
}
```

what i am trying to do is to build and concatinate a querystring using the class list from above.
for the following object:

```
List<classA> requestParams = ...
```

the query string should look like:
a=1&b=2&c=3

ordered by FieldName ascending

where IncludeInChecksum = true

FieldName = FieldValue

```
            preMD5= requestParams
                .Where(x=>x.IncludeInChecksum)
                .OrderBy(y=>y.FieldName)
                .Aggregate((i,j)=>(i.FieldName+ "=" +j.FieldValue));
```

this is where i am stuck.
thanks in advance

Comment: Your understanding of how `Aggregate` works is not correct. You probably just want a `Select` at the end.

Comment: So what is the result of your code?

Comment: there is no result.. i dont know how to continue from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to get all  ***name=value*** strings with the help of the `Select()` method. And then convert the result to array. After that just use `String.Join()` method to get the desired result.

[`Join(String, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.

```
var preMD5= requestParams
                    .Where(x => x.IncludeInChecksum)
                    .OrderBy(y => y.FieldName)
                    .Select(z => string.Format("{0}={1}", z.FieldName, z.FieldValue))
                    .ToArray();
preMD5 = string.Join("&", preMD5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Aggregate` aggregates values from different rows. You need to combine values from different fields. For this you use `Select`:

```
requestParms.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Select(f=>f.FieldName+"="+f.FieldValue)
```

This will return an IEnumerable of `name=value` strings. You can use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to combine them into one string.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been answered,
but still I wanted to provide my solution.

I used a dedicated method to build the query string parameter,
and an extension method to concat it all.

Hope this helps.

```
public class classA
{
    internal string FieldName { get; set; }
    internal string FieldValue { get; set; }
    internal bool IncludeInChecksum { get; set; }

    public classA(string fieldName, string fieldValue, bool includeInChecksum)
    {
        this.FieldName = fieldName;
        this.FieldValue = fieldValue;
        this.IncludeInChecksum = includeInChecksum;
    }

    public string ToQueryString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}={1}",
            this.FieldName,
            this.FieldValue);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var list = new List<classA> { 
            new classA("A", "1", true) ,
            new classA("D", "4", true) ,
            new classA("B", "2", false)  ,
            new classA("C", "3", true) 
        };

        var result = list.
            Where(o => o.IncludeInChecksum).
            OrderBy(o => o.FieldName).
            Select(o => o.ToQueryString()).
            ToStringEx("&");
    }

}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToStringEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string separetor = ",")
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return "null";
        }

        return string.Join(separetor, items.Select(o => o != null ? o.ToString() : "[null]").ToArray());
    }

}
```